# Embed iframes from Google Sheets to Google Sites

Tags: iframe, charts, google-sheets, google-sites

I am embedding some charts from Google Sheets to Google Sites.

To do this I select Publish chart -> Embed -> Select "Image" instead of "Interactive" and then copy the code in my Google Site as an iframe.

However, I Get the chart with low quality, pixelated, in my Google Site.

Is there any way to get the chart with higher quality?

Also, I have tried to Embed Interactive charts instead of an Image, but it does not work. Why is that?

Comment: This topic on webapps seems to address an identical issue as your [](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24315/downloading-charts-from-google-sheets-in-high-resolution). Look at the later answers for how users created solutions over time.

Comment: Hi @Tedinoz . I dont want to download the charts. I just want to embed the charts as iframes in my Google Site. When I try to embed an Interactive chart instead of an image, it doesnt work

Comment: I was responding to "Is there any way to get the chart with higher quality?"